# Cached HSQLDB tables not releasing memory after insertion

Tags: hibernate, memory-leaks, hsqldb

I am using HSQLDB with Hibernate + Hibernate Search.

I am providing the following configuration :

```
<property name="hibernate.connection.url">
            jdbc:hsqldb:file:${jar.path};
            hsqldb.write_delay=false;
            hsqldb.large_data=true;
            hsqldb.default_table_type=cached;
</property>
```

${jar.path} specifies the run time path of the directory where DB is to be created.

As I am saving objects using

```
session.save(object);
```

the memory usage keeps on increasing. After analyzing the heap dump, maximum retained heap is for the class :

```
org.hsqldb.RowAction
```

under the

```
org.hsqldb.lib.HsqlArrayList section
```

If i comment the session.save(object) line, the memory does not increase.
Is there any other configuration that is required to prevent saving the objects in memory in HSQL?

P.S. : All the session.save(obj) commands are batched using the following code.

```
session.save(obj);

if (batchCount.incrementAndGet() >= 100) {
   session.flush();
   session.clear();
   batchCount.set(0);
}
```

Comment: You need to commit the transaction. The RowAction objects are from uncommitted inserts and will disappear when you commit.

Comment: I am batching my save commands in a batch of 100 and flushing and clearning my session after that. I already tried commiting my transaction but to no avail.